# Is MySQL 8J driver class compatible with MySQL 5.1.x connector series?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

This section of the MySQL documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) states that API changes will be required when moving from 5.1.x to 8.0, however, can a db connection and with simple operations still work if attempting to use com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver with 5.1.x connector?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you wish to upgrade, i.e. which part of the system you wish to "move from 5.1 to 8.0": the server or the client (connector library)?

Comment: @GerardvanHelden, yes, I'm referring to the connector library, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html, the connector is not compatible with MySQL server version 5.1. The stated compatible server versions are 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0.

However, I wouldn't be discouraged myself to give it a try. If you have good reason to upgrade your app code, but keep your server version back, it might very well be worth a shot. Client/server protocols don't tend to change that much. Of course, this would involve testing your application code, but you would need to anyway.

That being said, obviously, upgrading your server is the better and more future-proof route.

Comment: I'm inquiring about the connector and by the way, MySQL connector 5.1.x is also compatible with server versions 5.6, 5.7 and 8.0, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html. I think this class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver is simply not compatible with 5.1.x connector but I didn't see it documented or maybe it's implied. Thanks for your inputs though!